# How write a function to shorten my list by cleaning it up in python

Tags: python

So lets just say I have a big data coming in that looks like this

```
bigData = [
    {
        "name": "item 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "item 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "item 2"
    },
    {
        "name": "item 2"
    },
    {
        "name": "item 3"
    },
    {
        "name": "item 3"
    },
    {
        "name": "item 3"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to write a function that will minimize that data into something like this

```
cleanedBigData = [
    {
        "name": "item 1",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "item 2",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "item 3",
        "quantity": 3
    }
]
```

if tried some stuff like this for example

```
cleanedBigData =  []


for i in bigData:

    for u in cleanedBigData:

        if i["name"] == u["name"]:

            i["quantity"] += 1
        
        else:

            cleaned_data = {
                "name": i.name,
                "quantity": 1
            }

            cleanedBigData.append(cleaned_data)
```

but it didn't work probably because the array was empty in the first place so the second `for` loop didn't get executed

how would you approach this problem?

thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a pythonic solution, you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), like this:

```py
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(d['name'] for d in bigData)
cleanedBigData = [{"name": name, "quantity": quantity} for name, quantity in c.items()]
```

For the learning opportunity, here's a solution based on your original code:

```py
cleanedBigData = []

for i in bigData:
    foundInClean = False # We need to "remember" if we found our element
    for u in cleanedBigData:
        if i["name"] == u["name"]:
            foundInClean = True # found it!
            u["quantity"] += 1
    if not foundInClean: # didn't find it, create new one and append it
        cleaned_data = {
            "name": i["name"],
            "quantity": 1
        }
        cleanedBigData.append(cleaned_data)
```

Comment: I would use `Counter(d['name'] for d in bigData)` instead.

Comment: @Francisco yea, shorter and more precise, editting to add it 

Answer (score 0):

The `Counter` in python can be used here. Here is a small example on how to:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

bigData = [
    {
        "name": "item 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "item 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "item 2"
    },
    {
        "name": "item 2"
    },
    {
        "name": "item 3"
    },
    {
        "name": "item 3"
    },
    {
        "name": "item 3"
    }
]


counter = defaultdict(int)  # initialise counter

# Count the number of occurances of each item
for i in range(0,len(bigData)):
    for item in bigData[i].values():
        counter[item]+=1

cleanedBigData = []

# Save the result as needed
for item, count in counter.items():
    cleanedBigData.append({"name": item, "quantity": count})
```

Result

```
[
    {'name': 'item 1',
     'quantity': 2
    },
    {'name': 'item 2',
     'quantity': 2
    },
    {'name': 'item 3', 
    'quantity': 3
    }
]
```

Read more about `counter` here: [RealPython.com](https://realpython.com/python-counter/#counting-objects-in-python)